# How \middle is defined in mleftright.sty?

Tags: math-mode, macros, e-tex

Process the following example with `etex`:

```
\input mleftright.sty
$\sin\mleft(x^2\middle|y^2\mright)$
\end
```

I wonder what is the definition of `\middle` - I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition is in `etex.ch`: `\middle` isn't a macro, but a primitive added by ε-TeX.
If you do `\show\middle` you get:

```latex
> \middle=\middle.
l.1 \show\middle

?
```

The ε-TeX manual (`texdoc etex`) describes it:

> [image: <code>\left</code> <code><delim></code> <code><math mode material></code> <code>\middle</code> <code><delim></code> <code><math mode material></code> <code>\right</code> <code><delim></code> (generalizing TeX’s <code>\left</code> <code><delim></code> <code><math mode material></code> <code>\right</code> <code><delim></code>) For each <code><math mode material></code> ε-TeX begins a new group, starting out with a new math list (always in the same style) that begins with a left boundary item containing everything processed so far. This group must be terminated with either ‘<code>\middle</code>’ or ‘<code>\right</code>’, at which time the internal math list is completed with a new boundary item containing the new delimiter. In the case of ‘<code>\middle</code>’, a new group is started again, in the case of ‘<code>\right</code>’, ε-TeX appends an Inner atom to the current list; the nucleus of this atom contains the internal math list just completed.]

Comment: _Off-topic_: there is a missing ``\`` in `right`... Do I get a check? ;-)

Comment: On the check (comment above): there's a comment near top of etex.ch which says "the change history which follows and the reward offered for finders of bugs refer specifically to TeX; they should not be taken as referring to e-TeX, ..." :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Just kidding, I know the check's are only for Knuth's TeX(book). Thanks for the reference, though :-) I wonder where/whether I should report this...